# User Affiliate Token Generator?

Tags: plugins, links, parameter

I want to add the feature if a user clicks on a Link which is already generated with a affiliate link:

```
www.example.com/id82312312312?mt=8&uo=4&at=AFFILIATE-ID
```

But if a user clicks on the link, the WordPress plugin automatically adds this at the end of the URL for every user.

```
www.example.com/id82312312312?mt=8&uo=4&at=AFFILIATE-ID&ct=USERNAME
```

I tried to at this to `functions.php` that I generated with [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.

```
if(function_exists("register_field_group")) { register_field_group(array ( 'id' => 'acf_testfeld', 'title' => 'TESTFELD', 'fields' => array ( array ( 'key' => 'field_58ef7574baf5e', 'label' => 'testfeld', 'name' => 'testfeld',), ), 'menu_order' => 0, )); }
```

Comment: i tried to at this to functions.php its generated with advanced custom fields for wordpress.

Comment: if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{
 register_field_group(array (
  'id' => 'acf_testfeld',
  'title' => 'TESTFELD',
  'fields' => array (
   array (
    'key' => 'field_58ef7574baf5e',
    'label' => 'testfeld',
    'name' => 'testfeld',

Comment: ),
  ),
  'menu_order' => 0,
 ));
}

Comment: Please do not post code inside comments. Better to edit your question and add your code.